# Enable scroll by dragging my stylus?

Tags: 11.04, wacom, mouse-scroll, bamboo

How can I configure my Wacom Bamboo Pen&Touch stylus to scroll when I hold one of the buttons on the stylus and drag with it? This is a standard supported operation on the Mac, but I can't find how to configure it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I've got absolutely no experience with the Wacom tablet but looking through many sites it is supported well in Ubuntu and can be configured to do many things.

One of the most comprehensive sites to look at is the [Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom) page for the Wacom tablet - it has many useful suggestions and workarounds as well as links to forums and other sites for development of the drivers in Ubuntu to support the tablet.